# How do you display "mm/dd/yyyy" instead of "12/31/1969" in date input fields when date is null?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date, angular-ui-bootstrap

Essentially I have a column in my database that is of date type but can be null. I have a form using Angular/Bootstrap that allows users to enter a date if they wish but they do not have to, for this I use Bootstraps form-control class and give the input a type of date.

Everything works saving the first time when the form is loaded with a null value for the date. The database saves it fine and all is good. However when I load a record into this form if the database shows a null value Angular/Javascript is displaying it as 12/31/1969 instead of "mm/dd/yyyy" as it does when it is initially loaded with null values. This causes an issue because if the user saves this form it takes the default 12/31/1969 as a real date and saves that as input.

I have tracked it through the console and I am 100% positive the date value is null ([image]) when it hits my model binding so I can't think of what to do in this scenario, I would really appreciate any pointers.

On pulling the data:

```
if (myDateFromDatabase !== null) { 
    myDateFromDatabase = new Date(myDateFromDatabase); 
}
```

In view:

```
<input ng-model="myDateFromDatabase" type="date" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: Show some code, please. Your question is off-topic and will be put On Hold otherwise.

Comment: More specifically, I'm asking for the controller or directive that's doing what you describe in your question.

Comment: This really sounds like you're getting an empty string (or even a 0) vs a `null` back for `myDateFromDatabase`... If you make that `if (myDateFromDatabase !== null && myDateFromDatabase !== '')` do you still get those results? If you put a `debugger` inside that `if` block, does your console land on it? I know you said you are 100% positive `myDateFromDatabase` is `null`, but you're here for a second set of eyes, so it wouldn't hurt to see that proof as well.

Comment: Posted it at the point you referenced if you need I can also show proof it carries forward all the way to binding in the controller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Angular needs to have any `input[date]` be a *valid* javascript `Date` object, otherwise it will default to an empty string, which will then default to 12/31/1969. Javascript `Date` objects must always have a valid `Date`.

If you want to be able to use a nullable `Date` object, you should set the default property to `undefined` and then when you bind your model, you can see if it's `null` first, and do nothing if it is.

```
var myDateFromDatabase = undefined; // if you get null back from database, you'll keep this undefined
```

Then when you fetch your data and apply it...

```
if (data.dateRetrieved !== null) { 
    // only make myDateFromDatabase an actual date if there is something stored
    myDateFromDatabase = new Date(data.dateRetrieved); 
}
```

And for your default text, add the `placeholder` attribute:

```
<input ng-model="myDateFromDatabase" type="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" class="form-control" />
```

Comment: I will try the undefined approach and report back! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks ! Basically on the null check I added else {myDateFromDatabase = undefined;} and worked perfectly. You are  a champ ragerory. For future people looking at this placeholder is not necessary.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it.

Answer (score -1):

Like isherwood said, this question is harder to answer without some code context.  I'll update my question if some is added.

Somewhere in your code you must be formatting the date.  If the javascript is formatting it from a date object, then you simply need to do something like:

```
if(some_date === null)
    some_date = 'mm/dd/yy;
else {
    //date formatting code
}
```

If your php or query formatting the date for you then if you were doing this for example on the frontend:

```
<input ng-attr-value="{{obj.date}}"/>
```

Then change that to:

```
<input ng-attr-value="{{obj.date === null ? 'mm/dd/yyyy' : obj.date}}"/>
```

Or alternatively do something similar when you've received the data back from the api.

**Edit/note:** You may have trouble with this method in angular 1.3+ if it's a date input field.

Comment: This does not answer the question and setting the date to a string 'mm/dd/yyyy' would  throw date formatting errors in Angular 1.3+ as it requires date object types.

Comment: @IfTrue Technically he asked for the value to be 'mm/dd/yyyy', not a placeholder.  I also didn't have much example in his question to go off (he's since added a lot), I answered the question as best I could.